# Executing JSTL condition on click of anchor tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to execute a condition on anchor of `href` with `jstl` tag.

```
<a href="#add" class="useradd">Add user</a>
```

I want to do:

```
if(anchor == add) {
  // do something
}
```

I don't know how to execute this condition through `href` anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because the browser doesn't send the anchor to the server. You need to do it with parameters and remove the `#` in `href`:

```
<a href="myjsp.jsp?pram1=add" class="useradd">Add user</a>
```

and then the `if` condition would be:

```
<c:if test="${param.pram1=='add'}">
    do something
</c:if>
```

Comment: I tried  <c:if test="${href=='#add'}">
  blabla
</c:if>  it doesn't work

Comment: Ah. Now I understand what you want. It is not possible because the browser don't send the anchor to the server. You need to do it with parameters.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do,but I want to stay in the same jsp page. if href is clicked go to a piece of html code and print it.

Comment: Then link to the same jsp page. Or what do you mean with `I want to stay in the same jsp page`.

Comment: I did, it gave me HTTP Status 404.

Comment: replace the `myjsp.jsp` with your directory + jsp file name informations. I don't know your structure.

Comment: <a href="users.jsp&pram1=1" class="useradd">Add user</a> form to add user, still have the same error , my current page , my same page is users.jsp, anyway thank you edze.

Comment: the directory? look at url in your browser. It must be the same after click on the link.

Comment: thanks a lot edze, I did it, your simple if+ onclick did the job :)

Comment: @abdo If it worked then why not accept this answer? Thanks. This [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might be useful as to why I am saying to accept it.

Comment: yes, I wrote the solution bellow, when I want to accept, I got a msg, you must have more reputations,sorry I'm new in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use javascript for your requirment. like onclick event etc.

Comment: I tried it with a button but it shows also other contents in my page.

Comment: what kind of contents does it show, could you post a snaps of your code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found:

```
<a href="#users.jsp&pram1=1" onclick="location='users.jsp?loc=fiche_ag&amp;cur=1' class="useradd">
```

now the `if` condition becomes:

```
<c:if test="${param.cur=='1'}">
     do what you want ...
</c:if>
```

Comment: now i see your error `href="#users.jsp&pram1=1"` have to be `href="users.jsp&pram1=1"` remove the `#`. You don't need the onclick.

Comment: no, I added # to neglect the href redirect, even I deleted it, I get the parameter from onlcik.